# Can I edit a cell formula without causing the cell to recalculate?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example, if I have

```
=INDEX(B1:B100000,MATCH("my_val",A1:A100000,0))
```

in a cell, how can I change that to

```
=INDEX(C1:C100000,MATCH("my_val",A1:A100000,0))
```

without triggering the (slow) Index-Match?

(I've already set calculations to manual, but Excel still recalculates a formula entered or modified by hand.)

Comment: You can set calculation to manual but then it applies to whole workbook and not just one cell.

Comment: I don't think you can. The way Excel sees it, you just entered a new formula and it checks for errors, thereby calculating the results. If you were changing the data which is calculated would be a different story, needing manual calculation to be triggered.

Answer (score 2):

You can set calculation to manual. But then it applies to whole workbook not just one cell. If   you are ok with that, here is how to do it:
[image]

**UPDATE:**
If this does not work then you can temporarily set the cell type to text and then key in the formula which will behave as text. Later, change cell type to general, go to cell, hit <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will calculate the formula.